# CSS - Indent all except first line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, indentation, line-breaks, content-length

**Update 2013-01-04**

- The flexbox solution makes very little extra HTML / CSS. However it's unclear if it can work in Firefox and IE10?
- To add minus characters to `:before` with CSS content instead of HTML is a better way to go.

**Information**

I have a table with some content. Depending on the depth I have a number of minus characters before the text.

**Problem / question**

I can't figure out how to make the text align right and the minus characters to align left, even when line break accur. The number of minus and the text length can vary.

**Example on jsfiddle**

Edit it if you like...

http://jsfiddle.net/Rjvc9/

**HTML if jsfiddle don't work**

```
<table>
    <td>            
        <span class="lines">----</span> <span class="text">My page that is far too long for it to fit on one row</span>
    </td>
</table>

<br>

This is how it should work.<br><br>

<table>
    <td>            
        <span class="lines">----</span> <span class="text">My page that is far<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;too long for it to fit<br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;on one row</span>
    </td>
</table>​
```

**CSS if jsfiddle don't work**

```
table {
    background: #eee;
    width: 150px;
}

td {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin: 40px;
}​
```

**My thoughts**

- I thougt i could use indent in a clever way but that don't seem to
  work.
- I like the display: inline. If it can be kept that way it would
  be nice, but maybe that's not possible?
- It should work on fewer minus characters and longer / shorter text.
- It don't have to work with old browsers.
- I prefer CSS before jQuery / javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your cells aren't going to be bordered, flexbox can work here for you.

```
td.dashed {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
```

Demo works with both a span or using content on a before psuedo element to contain the dashed.  Does not work on anything older than IE10.  Mozilla doesn't appear to like this, but it is supposed to support flexbox.

http://jsfiddle.net/Rjvc9/9/

Comment: Very interesting. I made it more simple to read. Will test this one out in my project. http://jsfiddle.net/Rjvc9/11/

Comment: Mozilla is apparently still following the old flexbox specification.  Chrome and Opera are following the current one.  http://caniuse.com/#search=flex claims IE10 is also following the old spec.

Comment: It is not possible to make it work the same in Firefox and IE10?

Comment: Definately an interesting solution, but it looks like the browser support is not quite there yet [(link)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes#Browser_compatibility) - but it works well in Chrome

Comment: @JensTörnell Theoretically, you could (I'm still learning how to use flexbox myself, so I can't help any further at this point in time).  You'd have to cover both old and current, where the current syntax is always listed last (similar to how both old and current gradient syntax for Webkit is done, see: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).

Answer (score 21):

#### Use a negative `text-indent`!

A `text-indent` indents the first line. So give it a negative value!

```
.first-line {text-indent: -5em; padding-left: 5em;}
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should do it:

```
display: block;
padding-left: 37px;
text-indent: -37px;
```

You will give a negative indent on the first line so this will be placed X pixels to the left. By giving the whole element a padding-left of the same amount of px this will place it all on the right place again.

Also see: http://jsfiddle.net/Rjvc9/3/

Note: `display: inline` will not work on this. `display:inline-block` will.

Comment: I checked in both Chrome and Firefox and this doesn't work for me, the `----` characters are all on their own line before the text and now the first line of text is no longer indented.

Comment: I thought on something like that but if the number of minus characters is changed it would not work because the indent is fixed to 37px.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS's `content` attribute, you can insert the minus characters into the page AND position/style them without the need to include them in your HTML or to wrap them in any tags.

I amended your example http://jsfiddle.net/cchana/Rjvc9/2/ and it now works by giving the cell some padding and a position attribute like so:

```
td {
    padding: 0 0 0 24px;
    position: relative;
}
```

I then added in the `----` characters to the beginning of the cell using `content` and then positioning it correctly:

```
td:before {
    content: '----';
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: I thought of that possibility but if the number of minus characters is changed it would not work because the indent is fixed to 24px.

Comment: but if you're changing the number of characters, you can change the size of the padding at the same time? For every `-` you need an extra 6px

Comment: Maybe. I have an unknown depth of minus characters. That would require inline CSS generated by PHP. I will do some testing.

Comment: Using the `content` property for injecting the dashes seems most appropriate, since the dashes aren't actually content:  they're decoration when used this way.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a `table` element, put the “minus characters” (actually, Ascii hyphens, formally HYPHEN-MINUS characters) in a column of their own. You should also make the markup valid (a `td` element can only be a child of `tr`).

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="lines">----</td>
    <td class="text">My page that is far too long for it to fit on one row</td>
</table>
```

In CSS, add `td { vertical-align: top; }`. (Or add the corresponding HTML markup, `<tr valign=top>`, for every `tr` element.

The columns will be left-aligned by default, and you can tune this as desired. On modern browsers, you won’t even need the `class` attributes, as you can use the selectors `td:first-child` and `td:first-child + td` for example.

Answer (score 0):

For inline displays you kind of have to mix things up, using a negative margin and a negative text indent. Here is a working jsfiddle with an example:

```
#thisList ul li a {
    color:#333;
    text-indent:-1.5rem;
    margin-left:-2rem;
    line-height:1;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/codesushi156/yzez2bj3/)